# Cannot connect to Azure SQL from SSMS v17.6

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I'm getting connection issue when connecting to Azure SQL from On-Premise SSMS. Even I tried using Data Migration Assistant to connect from On-Premise to Azure SQL.I added my IP address to the firewall settings in Azure SQL.

Here is the exception message *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*.

Please suggest me if I'm missing any settings.

Comment: Check that you're not behind a firewall preventing outbound TCP traffic on port 1433.

Comment: You can verify the SQL server instance name to connect to the Azure SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could verify the followings on your side:

- Whitelist the client IP in the [firewall of Azure SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule#create-a-server-level-ip-firewall-rule). It's a public IP from your client.
- By default, SQL Database communicates over port 1433. Outbound traffic over port 1433 might not be allowed by your network's firewall. You could open this port in the local firewall on the client machine or let your IT department opens port 1433 within a corporate network. You also could verify network connectivity via `telnet someservername.database.windows.net 1433` in the Command Prompt.
- Use a correct FQDN SQL server name to connect such as `xxx.database.windows.net`.
- Ensure you are using SQL Server Authentication. Use a correct login username and password.

You could get more details from this [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms).